# Bootstrapping with logistic regression in Python - constructing test vector

Tags: python, machine-learning, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to use bootstrapping to get an average estimate of the MSE of my model. I am attempting to follow this guide, for context: https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-the-bootstrap-method/ Here is my code:

```
models_mse = [None]*100
for i in range(100):
  boot = resample(X, replace = True, n_samples = math.floor(len(X) / 2),random_state = 1)
  y_new = [y for y in X if y not in boot]
  X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(boot, y_new, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
  reg = LogisticRegression()
  reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
  MSE = mean_squared_error(y_test, reg.predict(X_test))
  models_mse.append(MSE)
```

this produces the error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [497, 0]
```

Meaning, `y_new` is empty. From my understanding of bootstrapping, we treat our sample as the "population" and we resample with replacement on this pseudopopulation to generate more samples to estimate parameters of the pseudopopulation, namely in my case MSE. Here, I have some encoded data `X` using onehot. It looks like this:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., ..., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 1.],
       ...,
       [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., ..., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., ..., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

and is a numpy array:

```
>>>type(X)
numpy.ndarray
```

My question is the following: why is `y_new` empty when I have observed differences between `boot` and `X`? Furthermore, I have arbitrarily decided to have half the samples of the original sample. Is there a more systematic way to choose the number of samples when bootstrapping? And lastly, is my setup in general correct for the problem I am trying to solve?

Thanks.

Edit:
After some revisions from user comments, my new code is:

```
models_mse = [None]*100
for i in range(100):
  boot = resample(X_train, replace = True, n_samples = X_train.shape[0],random_state = 1)
  reg = LogisticRegression()
  reg.fit(boot, y_train)
  MSE = mean_squared_error(y_test, reg.predict(X_test))
  models_mse.append(MSE)
```

which does not throw any errors. However, the MSE is exactly the same for each model, which is strange as shouldn't `boot` be different for each iteration?

Comment: First of all, your bootstrapping method looks strange. The bootstrap sample you are creating is half the size of your original sample. On the other hand, the most common method of creating bootstrap samples requires for all bootstrap samples to be the same length as the original data. So I would put `n_samples = X.shape[0]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. How are the y vectors typically chosen when bootstrapping? I changed it to have `y_new = X[:,0]` and now my code works, but I am not aware of the accuracy of the results.

Comment: It also appears that the MSE for each iteration is exactly the same...

Comment: Finally, are you sure you need to bootstrap here? Why not just run a KFold cross-validation?

Comment: Someone who is much more knowledgeable on these topics than I recommended I try out bootstrapping. A different method may be better, but I'm gung-ho now on learning how I can fix this. I attempting to implement your changes as we speak.

Comment: @pavel I made an update to the code, feel free to peak if interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `y_new` is chosen from `X`:

```
y_new = [y for y in X if y not in boot]
```

You probably wanted to choose from `X`. It still won't work though because you cant do `in` operation for numpy arrays.
Also as [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-the-bootstrap-method/) post says, `resample` API doesnt give you out of bag observations for test set. However the good thing is that what we want from the API is fairly simple to implement. Also you probably dont want to use the same seed (random state) everytime while sampling.

```
models_mse=[]
for _ in range(100):
    train_idx = np.random.randint(0,len(X),size=(len(X),))
    test_idx = np.array([i for i in range(len(X)) if i not in train_idx])
    X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = X[train_idx], Y[train_idx], X[test_idx],Y[test_idx]
    model = LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    mse = MSE(Y_test, Y_pred) # replace by appropriate API/function
    models_mse.append(mse)

print("Bootstrapped MSE={}".format(sum(models_mse)/100))
```

I have used the same size for train set as the original dataset `X` as that is what I normally do. You can change it if you want.

Comment: Thanks! Though it appears your method of constructing the training and test data sets has depreciated on newest Pandas

Comment: @hkj447, No, not really. You can use `df.iloc` API for that

Comment: Hmm you are right (plus these are numpy arrays anyway, forgot that). Either way I am given another error: ```KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Int64Index([446, 808, 888, 490, 667,\n            ...\n            750, 560, 717, 797,  26],\n           dtype='int64', length=244)```. However, this is out of the scope of the question. I appreciate any thoughts on it though.

Comment: Not `loc`. Its `iloc`...here's the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Comment: Yes I used `iloc` and it gave the error that it cannotbe used for `numpy` arrays. This is the error that is generated by simply running your code.

Comment: you can use `tolist()` API on the numpy array to convert it to python list